# Data Recovery Problem

Tags: boot, mount, hard-drive

I'm new at Linux, so I promise no matter how simple the answer is, it will all be news to me. I've found a lot of questions online similar to mine, but I'm not having much luck with results. This system is presently running Ubuntu 13.10 and nothing else.

My girlfriend sold her laptop recently and prior to doing so she put about 10gb worth of data on my Linux machine. Recently the computer crashed and no longer boots up. I am running Linux off of an 8GB USB drive. I loaded the operating system by doing Try Linux. What I am trying to do is recover her 10gb of family photos. The rest of everything is irrelevant to me. On the left side is an image of the hard drive labeled 496 GB Volume. Clicking this does nothing. If I go to Files, it is also under Devices, but if I click it what I get is a floating box that states

Unable to access "496 GB Volume"

Error mounting /dev/sda1 at /media/ubuntu/9cca38c7-f6ee-41fc-95bc-c5817c0844c3: command-line `mount -t "ext4" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/sda1" "/media/ubuntu/9cca38c7-f6ee-41fc-95bc-c5817c0844c3" exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1,
      missing codepage or helper program, or other error
      In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
      dmesg|tail or so

Now I know this question has been asked repeatedly but I don't know what I am doing wrong. I would be grateful for any help. I have to save these photos.

Comment: Does a USB drive count as an Ubuntu disk? And how do I tell what partition table type I should use?

Answer (score 1):

1. Boot into live mode using ubuntu disk.
2. Install testdisk - a data recovery tool.
3. Run testdisk. It will show option to create log file . Just select create and press enter .
4. After that You will screen like this.Select proceed.[image]
5. Now it will ask for partition table type.[image]
6. Select  analyse.[image]
7. After analysing it will show you the partition with error which you
   were not able to access. Sometime it will ask for `deeper search` if normal search failed.[image]
8. Now select the partition and copy your data wherever you want.[image]

It should help you.